# Viewing a mongodb document using object id

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios, mern

I'm creating an inventory using mern stack. When I try to view products with following code it always returns 'No Matching Product' even though in my collection, there are matching products. I tested the backend using postman, and it does work. What could be the reason and how can I fix it?

```
const ViewProduct = () => {
  const {prodID} = useParams()
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);
  const [isCalling, setIsCalling] = useState(false);
 

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
      setIsCalling(true);

      await axios.get('https://localhost:4000/api/products/',{params:prodID}
      ).then(response => {
        setProduct(response.data)
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      })

      setIsCalling(false);
    };

    getProduct();
  }, [prodID]);

  if (isCalling) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (!product) {
    return <div>No matching products</div>;
  }

  return (
    <><div>
      <h2>{product.name}</h2>
      <p>Product ID: {prodID}</p>
      <p>Description: {product.descr.join(', ')}</p>
      <p>Type: {product.type}</p>
      <p>Sub-type: {product.sub_type}</p>
      <p>No of Stock Remaining: {product.noOfStockRemaining}</p>
      <p>Archived: {product.archived ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</p>
      <p>Archived On: {product.archived_on}</p>
      <Button>Delete</Button>
      <Button >Add Stock</Button>
      <Button>Back To Inventory</Button>

    </div>
    </>

  );
};
```

backend:

```
const getAProduct = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params
    //revisit ths validation after importing nanoid
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return res.json({ error: 'no matching products' })
    }
    const product = await Product.findById(id)

    if (!product) {
        return res.json({ error: 'no matching products' })
    }

    res.json(product)
}
```

Also I created this middleware to execute everytime a request is send so that i can see what the request is. This shows that I'm sending a get request when I use postman to test backend but it shows nothing when i try to do it from frontend.

```
 app.use((req, res, next) =>{
    console.log(req.path, req.method)
    next()
})
```

Update: I get this error in the console

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:4000/api/products/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)

I have already installed and configured CORS, and it works for other requests. i also tried adding `withCredentials:true` to axios parameters and it still did not work.

**EDIT: it was a typo in the axios url, i had typed 'https' instead of 'http' for localhost. Thank you everyone for help**

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the parameter with:

```
await axios.get(`https://localhost:4000/api/products/${prodId}`);
```

And declare the route as:

```
app.get('api/products/:id', getAProduct)
```